# "\n" not working when exported to .jar file

Tags: java, jar, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I have an output file for a program I have written.  It is written by a FileWriter and BufferedWriter.

```
    FileWriter errout = new FileWriter(new File("_ErrorList.txt"));
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(errout);
```

Later I write to the file using lines similar to.

```
    out.write("Product id:" + idin + " did not fetch any pictures.\n ");
```

When I simpily run the program in Eclipse, the output file is formatted correctly, with each message being written on a new line. However when I export to a .jar file, it no longer works and puts every message on a single line, as if the "\n" was not working.

Am I using the FileWriter/BufferedWriter incorrectly, or does it not work in a .jar file?

Comment: Replace `\n` with `System.getProperty("line.separator")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use '\n' directly. Either use `out.newLine()` to introduce a line break, or wrap the `BufferedWriter` into a `PrintWriter`, and use `out.println()`.

This has nothing to do with the `.jar` file, anyway. More likely is Eclipse being clever and showing you line breaks, while the operating system does not.

Comment: Alright, using out.newLine() fixed the issue.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4):

One, check that the line separator is valid.  Use System.getProperty("line.separator") as provided by @Andrew Thompson.

Another option if you're doing a lot of this writing new lines is to wrap your BufferedWriter in a PrintWriter.

```
  FileWriter errout = new FileWriter(new File("_ErrorList.txt"));
  BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(errout);

  PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(out);
  printWriter.println("Product id:" + idin + " did not fetch any pictures.");
```

Comment: I **knew** there must be a `println` close at hand, I just got distracted by another question when I went looking for it.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson been there done that.  I gave you as much credit as I could.  :)

Comment: *"I gave you as much credit as I could."*  Which amounts to 'more credit than I deserve'.  ;)  +1 to your answer, BTW.